# Can I run a bash command that came to my mind while writing another?

Tags: bash, terminal

When I'm in the terminal, I find myself writing a bash command and then I remember that I had to use another command first.

Example:

```
user$ python manage.py runserv...
```

and I remembered that I had to use

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

first for any new package.

---

Is it possible to run it without having to erase my first still incomplete command?

Thanks

Comment: In the future -- this class of question is a better fit for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com) or [unix.se] SE, being (as it is) about interactive use rather than script development.

Comment: You can make a syntax error or provide an invalid argument _on purpose_, then press Enter, ignore the error message and write the new command in a new prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ctrl+a` to go to the beginning of the line, then `ctrl+k` to yank your current line to the cut buffer.

Run your new command, then press `ctrl+y` to "yank" the text back out, inserting it at the current cursor position.